# How to you distinguish a symbol table from a regular hash variable?

Tags: perl, glob

Is there any way to tell whether a hash reference is referring to a symbol table?

That is, how could the function

```
sub foo {
    my ($hashref) = @_;
    ...
}
```

know whether it had been invoked as

```
foo( \%main:: )
```

rather than

```
foo( \%main )
```

?

The application is a function that sometimes `tie`'s hash variables, but I'd want to avoid trying to tie a symbol table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this can be done from the C API using `HvNAME`. The following is from [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#HvNAME):

> HvNAME
>
> Returns the package name of a stash,
>   or NULL if stash isn't a stash. See
>   SvSTASH , CvSTASH .
>
> 1. char* HvNAME(HV* stash)

Comment: I was just starting to deduce this from running `perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump(\%a::),Dump(\%a)'`. Thanks for the link so I can do less cargo-culting. Without XS you can still do something like `$is_a_symtable = do { $sv=B::svref_2object($hashref);ref($sv) eq 'B::HV' && $sv->NAME};`

Answer (score 3):

You could look for either keys ending in '::', which would indicate that it has other packages, or all the values are symbol refs.

- Of course, even here it would be hard to tell a stash from a hash that just storing symbols (for whatever reason). I was poking around with `B::svref_2object`, but even symbols from a stash stored in a regular hash would return something for `$sym->can( 'STASH' )`.

I think the thing you might do is descend through the symbol table and see if a stash points at the exact same memory location.

Kind of like this:

```
use Scalar::Util qw<refaddr>;
my %seen;

sub _descend_symtable {
    $calls++;
    my ( $cand, $stash_name ) = @_;
    my $stash = do { no strict 'refs'; \%{ $stash_name }; };
    return if $seen{ refaddr( $stash ) }++;
    return $stash_name if $cand == $stash;

    my $result;
    foreach my $s ( grep { m/::$/ } keys %$stash ) {
        $result = _descend_symtable( $cand, "$stash_name$s" ) 
            and return $result;
    }
    return;
}

sub find_in_symtable { 
    my $needle = shift;
    %seen      = ();
    return _descend_symtable( $needle, 'main::' );
}
```

The performance wasn't *terrible*.

Comment: This is a great start and would get me 95% of the way there, I think. This test would be ambiguous for empty packages (`foo(\%empty::package)` vs. `foo({})`) and could be spoofed for false positives `foo( { 'abc::' => *main::abc:: })` or false negatives (`$emptypkg::{"def"} = "xyz"; foo(\%emptypkg::)`). Anything more foolproof?